# HTML Video on Android - Mute / Unmute control not available

Tags: android, ios, html, html5-video

I have enabled `controls` in my video tag so that users can unmute the video when it is playing on Desktop, the issue I have having is that on Android it continues to play muted with control option to unmute, also on iOS, it plays unmuted by default.

My code is:

```
<video id="player" width="430" height="236" style="position:absolute; top:7px; left:52px;" poster="movie.jpg" muted autoplay controls>  
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <img width="430" height="236" style="position:absolute; top:7px; left:52px;" src="movie.jpg" />
</video>
```

I can't find any answer anywhere. Desktop works fine.

Answer (score 0):

on iOS devices you can't mute or change volume HTML video (:

http://blog.millermedeiros.com/unsolved-html5-video-issues-on-ios/